# OVZ6 DEBIAN 9 error: fs.inotify.max_user_watches 8192 how to increase to 524288?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, linux

Apache and rails are failing, error: fs.inotify.max_user_watches, error well explained at
https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers 
in a fresh OVZ6 server in Amsterdam. **How can we increase the current 8192 value to 524288 without all the server permissions?** Is this possible?

The same webhost fixed this fails in other of our OVZ6 servers in London increasing the value. How can we manage this situation without losing all the configuration work?

Raising doubts: Are yarn/npm so heavies for this environments? Could be this problem due an old OVZ server kernel?

Our development environment is:

- Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch), Linux 4.9.0-1-amd64, x86-64.
- Apache 2.4.25 (Debian).
- Mysql 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB, debian-linux-gnu (x86_64), readline 5.2.
- Phusion Passenger 5.1.12.
- Rvm 1.29.3.
- Ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-linux].
- Rails 5.1.4.
- Yarn v1.3.2.
- Npm 3.10.10.
- Webpack 3.10.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Webhosting has changed the server to another node (London) amplifying max watchers to 524288. In a few hours we configured it and duplicated the apps and websites. Presently all is running well and not raising rails errors.